# Adding, and multiplying 2D matrices

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I am deeply puzzled by my current homework assignment for one of my CS classes.

The problem is to create a method to multiply two 3x3 matrices. As well as creating another method to add two 3x3 matrices, then combine the two and display the output. There are 3 matrices in total, all user inputted.

Matrix 1 : (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Matrix 2: (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

Matrix 3: (0, 2, 4, 1, 4.5, 2.2, 1.1, 4.3, 5.2)

Result Output: (30, 26, 22, 85, 73.5, 56.2, 139.1, 118.3, 95.2)

In the output we are given, Matrix 1 * Matrix 2 + Matrix 3 = Ouput.

My main problem is displaying the correct numbers in the output, it seems very simple, but his numbers are completely off my numbers. I am very stumped in you only multiply and add once, yet no two numbers can equal up to 139.1 if that is true.

```
    import java.util.Scanner    
    public class Assignment8 {

      public static void printResult(                                                        
              double[][] m1, double[][] m2, double[][] m3, double[][] resultMatrix, char op1, char op2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < m1[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + m1[i][j]);

              if (i == m1.length / 2)
                System.out.print( "  " + op1 + "  " );
              else
                System.out.print( "     " );

              for (int j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + m2[i][j]);

              if (i == m1.length / 2)
                System.out.print( "  " + op2 + "  " );
              else
                System.out.print( "     " );

              for (int j = 0; j < m3[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + m3[i][j]);

              if (i == m1.length / 2)
                System.out.print( "  =  " );
              else
                System.out.print( "     " );

              for (int j = 0; j < resultMatrix[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + resultMatrix[i][j]);

              System.out.println();
            }
    }


    public static double[][] multiplyMatrix(double[][] m3, double[][] m4) {
        double[][] result = new double[m3.length][m3[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++)
                    result[i][j] = m3[i][j] * m4[i][j];
        }
                    return result;
    }

    public static double[][] addMatrix(double[][] m1, double[][] m2) {
        double[][] result = new double[m1.length][m1[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++)
                    result[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
        }
                    return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[][] m1 = new double[3][3];
        double[][] m2 = new double[3][3];
        double[][] m3 = new double[3][3];

        System.out.print("Enter Matrix 1: ");   
        for(int row = 0; row <m1.length; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < m1[row].length; column++) {
                m1[row][column] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter Matrix 2:");
        for(int row = 0; row <m2.length; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < m2[row].length; column++) {
                m2[row][column] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter Matrix 3:");
        for(int row = 0; row <m3.length; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < m3[row].length; column++) {
                m3[row][column] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        double multiply[][] = multiplyMatrix(m1, m2);
        double add[][] = addMatrix(multiply, m3);
        double resultMatrix[][] = addMatrix(add, multiply);

        printResult(m1, m2, m3, resultMatrix, '*', '+');        
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on how to do a matrix multiplication using a simple iterative method. Hint: you don't just multiply the numbers in one matrix with the corresponding numbers in the other. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm

Comment: @Refrain94 - Are these vector matrices? I remember working with Calculus in CS, therefore a vectorized matrix multiplication would be related to the 'Cross Product'... http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CrossProduct.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you used to multiply your matrices is wrong. Take a look at [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I've spent the last 2 hours blowing my brain up going through the code, I figured adding and multiplying arrays would use the same logic. Just going number by number, 9 * 1, 2 * 8, etc.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, Phoenix pointed me in the right direction, I simply edited the multiplication method to execute properly, and eureka it worked!